# Soldering wires to 12 V car plugs?

Tags: soldering, wire, automotive, plug, terminal

Many of the cheaper lighter adapter plugs do not come with screws for connecting the wires to them, but rather with just the bare metallic contacts - to which I am supposed to do what, solder the plus and minus wires in such a vibration-rich environment?

Here is an image of the terminals that I was talking about:

[image]

Comment: Chrimp tool. It's what the auto industry uses.

Comment: https://powerwerx.com/cigbuddy-cigarette-lighter-powerpole-adapter

Comment: @winny perhaps there was a misunderstanding. How would I use a crimp tool on the terminals from the photo above ?

Comment: From that photo I don't see anywhere to connect anything.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can twist the appropriate leads together and solder them. Be sure to heat shrink or tape the connections afterwards to prevent shorts.

Or use a block terminal. Or crimp. It’s up to you. All of these would hold fine if done right.

**edit per new image** First remove the metal parts from the plastic case. Apply flux. Solder your leads directly to the surface. Clean flux residue. Reinsert the parts back to the plastic case.

Note there is a small pre-drilled hole where your negative lead should be inserted before soldering. Make sure your solder flows through and plugs the hole.

Comment: @winny Maybe I was not very clear. Can you check out the the photo I have added ?

Comment: edited per the new photo

Answer (score 2):

I would normally scrape down, file or sand-paper a portion of the metal surface to de-oxidise it, solder directly onto the flat surface and tie a knot on the cable inside the strain relief so that it can't be pulled out and the joints never experience significant stress. If you haven't room for a knot a cable tie around the outer insulation can suffice.

[image]

*Figure 1. Mechanical security of wire before soldering. Source: Building an effects pedal.*

A better approach might be to drill a small hole near the edge to make a solder lug. Tin the wire, insert it through the hole, bend over (the wire) and solder.

Answer (score 2):

Your photo is missing the parts used for the positive (centre) connection, which prevents detailed suggestions for that. However, for the negative (outside) connection, notice the "notch" which I have marked here in blue:

[image: Original car cigarette lighter plug with notch marked]

I have seen plugs of a similar style, where the negative wire is soldered into that notch.

As another example, this next photo shows the inside of a car USB charger, showing the soldering to its internal connections. The centre connection to the car's socket is made from that visible spring with its soldered connection, via a 1.25 inch fuse, to a small metal "cap" which is visible when this plug is fully assembled:

[image: Inside of car USB adapter plug showing soldering]

So in summary:

- In your plug, the "notch" in that negative metal part seems the likely intended soldering location. Don't try to do that soldering with the metal still in the plastic housing, as you might melt nearby plastic.
- Consider how you will implement fusing, since a typical car will allow 10A via its 12V (cigarette lighter) socket, which is enough to cause a fire.
- Some cheap equipment has no "strain relief" on the connections i.e. no attempt to add mechanical fixings and so any "pull" on the wire (and vibration) acts on the soldered joints. Obviously this causes problems. The answer by *Transistor* already addresses some options for that.

Comment: You really took the time! strain reliefs do not concern me much; after all, the vibration (or the "pull" on those soldered joints) are mostly coming from the inside of the plug, not from the outside. As for the second picture - I am ok with the red wire, but that poor black fellow is going to take a lot of vibrations. On the other hand, those car chargers don't go bad all that often, do they ?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, just wired one exactly like yours.

1. Solder your positive wire to the same solder point where the resistor is soldered to the center square plate.
2. Solder your negative wire to to the solder point where your LED is soldered to the side contact.

What this does is allow 12v direct through the wires to your device and 12v to the resistor to drop it down to stop burning out the LED.
The Resistor and LED are not required so can be cut out/removed if desired.

Comment: The question is how to do it in a manner that is mechanically sound in a vibration-rich environment. Not _where_ to solder.